# How to close a modal dropdown within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My application uses a modal drop down window to provide the user with basic sign up inputs to enter information like the email address and password for their account they are making

I'm trying to figure out how to close a modal drop down window after the user successfully signs up.

I tried using the following snipet of code:

```
$('#signupModal').modal('hide');
```

When using this, I get an error saying `'$' is no defined`

I was told this just meant including jQuery like so:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

This didn't resolve the error. I'm wondering if there's a dependency that I'm missing that I'm not aware of.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you including the jQuery script _before_ you try using it?

Comment: @Shaun Could you share more code HTML JS or if you are using any plugin? Also make sure to include `script` at the top of HTML in head tags and include jquery code inside doc ready function.

Comment: How can I be sure that it's being included before I use it? I figured that if I just add the script tag to my index.html it would just load it like every other dependency that I have included in there.

Comment: @pratikwebdev I tried adding the script tag at the stop of the HTML file but that didn't change anything. I'm not sure what extra code to include in the original question that would be of benefit. I'm pretty sure I'm not running any addition plugins

Comment: @ShaunODonovan Dropdown is on login page and after login successful is user navigating to another page or login is done with ajax?